# Segfault when puting cin value into array

Tags: c++, std

Here is all of my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream fin("cereal.in");
    ofstream fout("cereal.out");

    int n, m, f, s;
    cin >> n >> m;

    int c1[n];
    int c2[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> c1[i] >> c2[i];
        c1[i]--;
        c2[i]--;
    }

    vector<int> fm(m, -1);
    set<int> fs;
    vector<int> ans;
    for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i++){
        if(fs.find(c1[i]) == fs.end()){
            fs.insert(c1[i]);
        }else{
            if(fs.find(fm[c1[i]]) == fs.end()){
                fs.insert(fm[c1[i]]);
            }
        }
        fm[c1[i]] = c2[i];
        ans.push_back(fs.size());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << ans[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

In the first for loop when `i = n-1`, I'm getting a `Segmentation fault: 11`. I used a cout call after the cin in that for loop to find this information.

What is the reason for this? It was working fine a couple of minutes ago and I didn't even touch this part of the code and it stopped working. I'm using VS Code, but even when I use an online compiler it doesn't work. Here is the input I am giving:

```
4 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
```

Please help me. This isn't the first time I'm having a problem like this.

Comment: Varaible length arays `int c1[n];`, `int c2[n];` are not in the standard C++. *I used a cout call after the cin in that for loop to find this information* better is using a debugger.

Comment: It doesn't work with vectors either

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i++){ // <------
        if(fs.find(c1[i]) == fs.end()){
            fs.insert(c1[i]);
        }else{
            if(fs.find(fm[c1[i]]) == fs.end()){
                fs.insert(fm[c1[i]]);
            }
        }
        fm[c1[i]] = c2[i];
        ans.push_back(fs.size());
    }
```

Change to `i--`. You're accessing `c1[i]` with out of bound index.

Comment: I am stupid. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have an array index out-of-bounds bug, causing the program to access data where it shouldn't.

> for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i++){

In the above statement the integer `i` wraps around until it overflows, thus indexing `c1` into forbidden regions of memory.

The OS is alerted of the memory violation and killed the misbehaving program. When this happens the program is said to encounter a segmentation fault.